# Need to identify which button caused a modal jump using Storyboards

Tags: xcode, storyboard, modal-dialog

Does anyone know if I can identify which button sent me to a view controller using Storyboards, where a button makes a modal call to a view controller?

I have multiple buttons and view controllers that I'd like to jump to, but I want to use one view controller code base to process all of modal jumps. I'd like one viewcontroller.m file to understand which button was pressed and take action based on that.  There doesn't appear to be a clear description of how the whole "segue" operations work; It's all bits an pieces.

I tried to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method by letting my button attach to an IBAction. It seems silly because I don't need IBActions defined using modals. I also went the route of the `prepareForSegue` but it demands a navigation controller (which I don't think I need).

I guess it's nice to force people to do research but I have 16 hours into this one and I followed all the links to no avail including one insertion of a nag controller that blew away a bunch of functional segues that I had working.

Is there an easy way to pass a variable from one VC to another that's set prior to a button push? Maybe dirty stuff like that is needed but it would be nice to just be able to reference the segue you want in the modal button and have just that info passed to the "view did load" of the new UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The method *prepareForSegue:* is what you need, and it does not require you have navigation controller if you use modal style segue. From [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), what it does is:

> Notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed.

Make sure you have set the segue identifier in your storyboard, for example in the screenshot below I set it as PushModalViewController:

[image]

Then in your originating view controller, use the *prepareForSegue* method to set the property of the destination view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PushModalViewController"]) {
        TargetViewController *targetViewController = (TargetViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //set the property of the target view controller here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I decided to include the target view controller in the source, then I could update the label on the target during the "PrepareForSegue".  That allowed the target to select the proper file we wanted to show.